# How to remove a level of nesting from XML created by serialisation

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following class.

```
public class SerialisableClass
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName ="title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "repCycle")]
    public RepCycle RepCycle { get; set; } 
}

public class RepCycle
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [XmlArray("data")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "item")]
    public List<int> Items { get; set; }
}
```

If I serialise this...

```
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_filename))
        {
            XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerialisableClass));
            serialiser.Serialize(writer, myObject);
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

it gives me the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerialisableClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <title>Hello, World</title>
  <repCycle>
    <data>
      <data>
        <item>25</item>
        <item>23</item>
        <item>15</item>
      </data>
    </data>
    <data>
      <data>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
      </data>
    </data>
    <type>0</type>
  </repCycle>
</SerialisableClass>
```

But that is one `<data>` level too many. What I want is something more like...

```
  <repCycle>
    <data>
      <item>25</item>
      <item>23</item>
      <item>15</item>
    </data>
```

...etc.

How can I achieve this? I can't remove the `RepCycle` class (and just store it as a `List<Data>`) because then I won't be able to have the `Type` element. Also, I have tried making `Data` just a `List<List<int>>` but then I get the errors...

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>
> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List>'

I have read that multidimensional arrays are not supported by the serialisation, so I assume the same goes for multidimensional lists.

Comment: [XmlArray("data")] and [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "item")] are adding the extra layer of tags.  Use [XmlElement] instead.

Comment: @jdweng - Thanks a million - thought I needed the XmlArray to call the items `<item>` but [XmlElement(ElementName="item") did the same thing, if you make that an answer I'll accept it...